# Are there any "enterprise ready" functional programming languages?

Tags: java-ee, functional-programming, lisp, enterprise-development, ml

By "enterprise ready" I am referring to availability of tools: dependency management, build management, message servers, databases, application platforms and servers, and are secure and scale well?

For example, is there a lisp (or ML) alternative to j2ee?

Please exclude FP's ported to JVM or .NET CLR.

EDIT:  I know that one could use an FP jvm port i.e. clojure or F# on .NET CLR however I am curious to know if it is possible to develop a purely functional application for the enterprise without the JVM or CLR?

Comment: Anything wrong with [F#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight +1. You should add more details and post that as an answer.

Comment: I am intentionally trying exclude the JVM and .NET CLR from this discussion.  I know there are FP ports to the JVM and F# is there for .NET.

Comment: It's seems a bit odd to exclude JRE and .NET CLR explicitly, considering that they're the layers that provide most of what you consider to define what "enterprise ready" is. Without libraries and build tools, you could also say that C or C++ aren't enterprise ready, yet I'm fairly sure they're used in a number of companies.

Comment: Many of the tools you've listed are nothing but crutches designed to leverage the architectural issues of the OOP languages.

Comment: Why is it migrated? Seems like it's related to programm"ing" and not programm"ers"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have [Haskell for Enterprise Linux](http://justhub.org/). The haskell wiki even includes a [survey](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Enterprise_Haskell) page about how to use Haskell in the Enterprise.

Erlang (as mentioned by Chris) is definitely also a [good suggestion](http://veldstra.org/whyerlang/). It is built to scale, be fault-tolerant and stay in continuous operation for many years.

Personally I'm more of a fan of the static type system that Haskell has.

Comment: Interesting link to "Haskell for Enterprise Linux". However, I'm not sure I'd consider a project that released its alpha version about 2 months ago and its first beta 3 days ago as (enterprise) ready just yet. Ready soon, hopefully...

Comment: Haskell is mature enough (almost 22 years) and widely used enough in industry, but that particular project isn’t such a good example.

Comment: The OP explicitly said "Please exclude FP's ported to JVM or .NET CLR." Erlang has been ported to the JVM, ergo it is not acceptable by the OP. There are also both .NET and JVM ports of Haskell, which, again, means that they are not acceptable.

Comment: Haskell has native compilers.  You aren't limited by CLR/JVM runtimes.

Comment: @Jörg Are you sure there are Haskell ports to the JVM? Please provide evidence. (dead/incomplete projects excluded)

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I only know of the Haskell.net project which is from 2003. However they haven't released anything yet. In general there doesn't seem to be any production quality, working, backends, however some FFI interfaces have been created, according to the [wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC:FAQ#.NET.2FJVM_Availability). Anyways as both of them was originally intended and build with native compilers, I would say they in fact are very acceptable, unlike Clojure and Scala which purposely targets JVM/CLR.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it is the conversation I was hoping to see.  I wanted to know if there were alternatives to JVM/CLR ports not because I don't want to use the JVM I intend to, I simply wanted to know if they existed.

Answer (score 12):

I don't use Erlang, but I know someone who does, and from everything he's described it as it sounds like exactly what you are looking for.  (It was designed by an enterprise (Ericsson) for enterprise use, after all.)

Comment: There is a quote from the inventor in an interview: "In telecoms, downtime of a few seconds a year is just not acceptable!"

Comment: The OP explicitly said "Please exclude FP's ported to JVM or .NET CLR." Erlang has been ported to the JVM, ergo it is not acceptable by the OP.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm pretty sure the OP is interested in non-JVM non-CLR "enterprise-ready" functional languages. i.e. A functional language is not to be considered "enterprise-ready" solely on the basis of having been ported to JVM or CLR. It would be very strange to **exclude** a language from this discussion solely because there is another implementation of it on the JVM!

Answer (score 10):

Common Lisp has a long history of being used professionally.

It has two commercial implementations:

http://www.franz.com/

http://www.lispworks.com/

And several high-quality open source implementations.

Comment: Common Lisp isn't really a functionnal programming language, you can do things the way they're done in functionnal programming language but that's not often the case. it's a multi-paradimg language. So you use functionnal ease when you need it, object or imperative style when you need it and so on. But I think that's a great language to build large and robust system that are meant to stay for more than 5 years.

Comment: Lisp is ideal to me.  I'm actually strongly considering taking the plunge into Clojure since interop b/w JVM is very seamless I can introduce it to other projects in phases :)

Comment: @Daimrod: functional has 1 n, not two. You are right, it's not a pure functional language. It does, however, support functional programming. Also I like it. ;)

Comment: @ReubenPeter-Paul: if I had to work with a JVM codebase, I would work with Clojure by preference, because of the interop capabilities. :-)

Comment: @ReubenPeter-Paul: uh my bad and I can't edit it anymore :(. Anyway, if you had to use the JVM but not the java API you could look at [ABCL](http://common-lisp.net/project/armedbear/) because it's a complete Common Lisp implementation thus your program will also run with other Common Lisp implementation.

Comment: The OP explicitly said "Please exclude FP's ported to JVM or .NET CLR." Common Lisp has been ported to both the JVM (several times, actually) and the .NET CLR, ergo it is not acceptable by the OP.

Comment: One kind of tools that was explicitly asked for in the question was application servers, so this should be relevant: [Core-Server, a Common Lisp application server](http://labs.core.gen.tr/).